# Can libvirt be used for managing virtual devices which are not PCs?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual, printers, libvirt

I work in developing and creating virtual printers, with QEMU as the hypervisor (no KVM-only Qemu). Can libvirt library be used to manage virtual printers? Currently, I am investigating on how to convert the qemu command line parameters into dom.xml and try bringing up the virtual printer using virsh. I see that libvirt adds it's own parameters apart from the one provided (like for example vga), which are more suitable for a PC and not necessary for virtual devices like a printer.

Has livirt been successfully used to virtualize other devices or is it specifically aimed only for a PC environment?

Answer (score 0):

Libvirt will only automatically add an <video> element for VGA, if you have asked for a <graphics> element. So you can just leave out the latter to avoid this extra VGA device being added. What you're trying todo is pretty uncommon, so there may be other edge cases you hit like this.

Comment: Since it is a virtual printer with a display, I need the graphic element. I was able to overcome the vga error by specifying qlx as the type but as you have mentioned I am hitting a snag at every point. Like for example, we have a customized usb host controller, which I pass as a qemucommandline parameter, but libvirt adds lsi by default, which causes pci bus error. Any reference of emulation of virtual devices which are not standard OS type would be helpful